# Simple date format in java, Parse Exception

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

here is my date String : **"07SEP2014 00:00"**

and this is the code that convert string to date :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy HH:mm").parse(dateString);
```

and i'm getting parse exception. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine when I tried it. `Sun Sep 07 00:00:00 BST 2014`

Comment: Works fine for me too. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Above code works fine with JDK 6 & 7. See my answer.

Comment: works for me too [DEMO](http://ideone.com/ILD2CX)

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07SEP2014 00:00"  this is the stack trace there is noting more

Comment: Maybe you should check your strings for unprintable characters.

Comment: What is ur runtime environment ? Add some more code for better understanding.

Comment: i added full stack trace

Comment: as runtime enviroment i use jdk 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code works - as long as your System has a Locale where SEP = September.
You could set the Locale to be sure about that:

```
Date result = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy HH:mm",Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your date format based on pattern. More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html#datepattern) on customizing it.

**Edit:**
Case is important here. **SEP** should be like **Sep**

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy HH:mm");
    Date today = new Date();
    today.setMonth(8);
    String result = formatter.format(today);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output: **10Sep2015 15:08**

Edit 2: 
   Your example is also working.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy HH:mm");
    Date result = formatter.parse("07Sep2014 00:00");
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Output: **Sun Sep 07 00:00:00 IST 2014**

Comment: I've also tried to changed SEP to Sep but it didnt change anything. it gives me the same error

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07Sep2014 00:00"

Comment: @CengizDogan: I have parsed you date also in Edit 2. Your code also should work. Which Java version you are using?(This does not effect the output)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateParse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String date = "07SEP2014 00:00";
        try {
            Date dateParse = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy HH:mm").parse(date);
            System.out.println(dateParse);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
Sun Sep 07 00:00:00 IST 2014
```